# PHP - Sort array with another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Is there an easy way to sort an array with a variable array made for this task?
For example:

```
$fruits [
   'Apple' => '12',
   'Cherry' => '10',
   'Lemon' => '34', 
   'Peach' => '6'
]

$order [
   1 => 'Peach',
   2 => 'Other',
   3 => 'Lemon',
   4 => 'Other2',
   5 => 'Apple',
   6 => 'Cherry',
   7 => 'Other3'
]
```

I'd like to return this kind of array:

```
$ordered_fruits [
   'Peach' => '6',
   'Lemon' => '34',
   'Apple' => '12',
   'Cherry' => '10'
]
```

Comment: See this example of array combine function may it will help
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_combine

Comment: no sorting, just search and make a new array..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ordered_fruits = array();
foreach($order as $value) {

   if(array_key_exists($value,$fruits)) {
      $ordered_fruits[$value] = $fruits[$value];
   }
}
```

Comment: great, i took little bit time to give answer.

Answer (score 11):

make it with php functions:

```
$new = array_filter(array_replace(array_fill_keys($order, null), $fruits));
```

Comment: how funny the PHP functions are....., We did a lot of code and you did it with some library functions.

Comment: Yes, it's library has so many funs that if not the SO i forgot half of them  :)

Comment: This is superb, it works perfectly for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
$fruits = array(
   'Apple' => '12',
   'Cherry' => '10',
   'Lemon' => '34', 
   'Peach' => '6'
);

$order = array(
   1 => 'Peach',
   2 => 'Other',
   3 => 'Lemon',
   4 => 'Other2',
   5 => 'Apple',
   6 => 'Cherry',
   7 => 'Other3'
);

$result = array();
foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
  if ( array_key_exists($value, $fruits) ) {
    $result[$value] = $fruits[$value];
  }
}
print_r($result );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Technique of sorting:**

```
$result = array();

foreach($order as $value){
    if(array_key_exists($value, $fruits)){
        $result[$value] = $fruits[$value];
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
print_r($result);

Array
(
    [Peach] => 6
    [Lemon] => 34
    [Apple] => 12
    [Cherry] => 10
)
```